# How to pass list values for a choice field in a datagrid field in Dexterity?

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I have datagridfield in my Dexterity content type, using collective.z3cform. I have an interface classes, which defines the value_type as DictRow for the main datagridfield in my content type.

```
class IAssessment(interface):
    assessment_item=schema.Choice(
        title=u"Assessment Item",
        values=[u"Item 1",u"Item 2"],
        required=False
    )
    reference=schema.TextLine(title=u"Reference",required=False)


class Application(form.Schema,IImageScaleTraversable):
    form.widget(app_assessment=DataGridFieldFactory)
    app_assessment=schema.List(
        title=u"Application Assessment",
        value_type=DictRow(title=u"Application Assessment",schema=IAssessment)
    )
```

Is it possible to provide  values for IAssessment under assessment_item field based on catalog query using portal_catalog from other content types. I got an errorr when I insert catalog=getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog') since context is not defined, even if I put a parameter context in IAssessment, still I got the same error. Is there a way I can do catalog query in an interface class, if not are there any alternative ways?

Comment: what is the error you get? can you post it here?

Comment: NameError: name 'context' is not defined. -> That is when i insert the catalog=getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog') inside IAssessment.

Comment: To answer part of your question: No, you can't use a catalog query in your schema. Schema definitions get evaluated _once_, long before the ZCA is up and the catalog is available. Use [vocabularies](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/referencemanual-all-pages) and a context source binder.

Comment: Look at the vocabularies documentation: http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/vocabularies

Comment: I know this is an old issue but I recently got dinged by this. It appears to be a problem with sub-schemas used with the DictRow field from collective.z3c.datagridfield. If you try to use a ContextSourceBinder on one of those fields "context" is returned as z3c.form.interfaces.NO_VALUE.

I was able to get around this by ignoring "context" and just getting the portal object with getUtility(IPloneSiteRoot)

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want a context source binder, which is a form of [dynamic vocabulary](http://dexterity-developer-manual.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/vocabularies.html#dynamic-sources).

```python
from zope.schema.interfaces import IContextSourceBinder
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

@grok.provider(IContextSourceBinder)
def assessmentItems(context):
    catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
    return SimpleVocabulary.fromItems(
        (result.getId(), result.getObject()) for result in catalog(...)
    )
```

In your field definition, you then pass this in as `vocabulary`:

```
assessment_item=schema.Choice(
    title=u"Assessment Item",
    vocabulary=assessmentItems,
    required=False
)
```

Comment: I got an error: AttributeError: portal_catalog inside def assessmentItems(context)

Comment: I forgot to mention how it should be referenced in the form. I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: I got an error on my instance and it says only AssertionError:

Comment: Can you maybe try posting the entire feedback so we have something we can actually debug?

Comment: File "/home/user01/.buildout/eggs/zope.schema-3.7.1-py2.6.egg/zope/schema/_field.py", line 249, in __init__
    or IBaseVocabulary.providedBy(vocabulary))
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/home/user01/dev/mysite.site/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 15.2-15.55
 
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/home/user01/dev/mysite.site/src/ebpls.app/ebpls/app/configure.zcml", line 11.2-11.27
    AssertionError:

Comment: When I use source=assessmentItems, it doesn't have an error. The error will come out if I will insert the line catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog') inside def assessmentItems

Comment: Can you use pdb to find out what `context` is at that point? It may not be what I think it is because of the way you're using it inside a `List` field...

Comment: I now added import pdb; pdb.set_trace() after catalog= getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog') inside def assessmentItems, but there are no additional errors that could give a hint, the last statement on the errors is AttributeError: portal_catalog.

Comment: If you place it _before_ that line, execution will stop before it and you can inspect `context`.

Comment: I've now tested this against a `List` field using the `DataGridFieldFactory` widget, just in case there was some conflict there, and it works perfectly. There's something else in your code that is conflicting here, I believe.